# how do I multiply list elements by a constant if the element satisfies a condition

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list

```
list={-1,0,1,2,3};
```

I wish to multiply any element greater than 0.5 by a constant, say 5.0 so that I wind up with

```
list = {-1,0,5,10,15}
```

without using a Do loop.

I'm hoping it is crazy simple.

Thanks again in advance.

Comment: `If[# > .5, 5 #, #] & /@ list`?

Comment: Dang, that does it nicely. I'm starting to get the feel for the & /@ construct.

Comment: @TomMozdzen Those are two separate constructions: the ...#...& notation for [anonymous functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html), and /@ for [map](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html). You could use one or the other, or neither as in `tom[x_]:=If[x>.5,5x,x];Map[tom,list]`

Comment: If you're not yet comfortable with slots (`#` +`&`): `Function[x, If[x > .5, 5 x, x]] /@ list`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(1 - UnitStep[# - .5]) # + 5 UnitStep[# - .5] # &@list
```

or

```
 # (5 UnitStep[# - .5] /. 0 -> 1) &@list
```

or

```
If[# > .5, 5 #, #] & /@ list
```

> `{-1, 0, 5, 10, 15}`

Comment: I like the 3rd one the best, but the 1st two also offer alternative methods. Sure wish there was an example page with a ton of these to get this syntax down pat.

Answer (score 6):

Using [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html) with a [level spec](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LevelsInExpressions.html) works as well:

```
Replace[list, n_ /; 0.5 < n :> 5*n, {1}]
(* {-1, 0, 5, 10, 15} *)
```

Here, `{1}` means that you try to replace each expression at level $1$ (and *only* level $1$) for replacement, and `:>` is syntactic sugar for [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html), which means the right hand side (`5 * n`) is only evaluated after the pattern on the left hand side (`n_ /; 0.5`) matches, and is evaluated each time it matches.

Comment: Ah - got it, but the condition should be n > 0.5. Also, could you please explain what the {1} does and what the :> does? is the :> an assignment?

Comment: Shorter version... `list /. (i_ /; i > 0.5 :> 5 i)` (ie, harder to read...)

Answer (score 2):

```
Function[x, If[x > 0.5, 5 x, x], Listable][list]
(* {-1, 0, 5, 10, 15} *)
```